# PIG Script Statistics Always Zero (0) in MapReduce Mode From Jar File not Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, maven, hadoop, apache-pig

I am using `hadoop2.2 and pig-0.12`.

I have created Maven Project for Calling PIG Script in JAVA application using MapReduce Mode. My code is working fine in Eclipse (It show correct statistics).

But when i build into JAR file, Execute the Same Job getting Statistics always shows zero, but output file is generated with proper results.

Below is the response i actually get while running the PIG script application in Terminal window.

```
Input(s):
Successfully read 0 records from: "/user/hdfs/input/100RecordsDataInput.csv"

Output(s):
Successfully stored 0 records in: "hdfs:/user/hdfs/out/980"

Counters:
Total records written : 0
Total bytes written : 0
Spillable Memory Manager spill count : 0
Total bags proactively spilled: 0
Total records proactively spilled: 0
```

I don't know what i am doing wrong.

Here is my POM.xml file.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>cloudera</id>
            <url>https://repository.cloudera.com/artifactory/cloudera-repos/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <groupId>PIGScript</groupId>
    <artifactId>PIGScript_Sample</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>PIGScript_Sample</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>      <!-- <dependency> <groupId>org.apache.hbase</groupId> <artifactId>hbase-client</artifactId> 
            <version>1.0.0-cdh5.4.4</version> </dependency> <groupId>org.apache.hbase</groupId> 
            <artifactId>hbase-server</artifactId> <version>1.0.0-cdh5.4.4</version> </dependency> -->


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
            <artifactId>hadoop-client</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.0-cdh5.4.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
            <artifactId>hadoop-hdfs</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.0-cdh5.4.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-httpclient</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.pig</groupId>
            <artifactId>pig</artifactId>
            <version>0.12.0-cdh5.4.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.antlr</groupId>
            <artifactId>antlr-runtime</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.2</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
            <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>dk.brics.automaton</groupId>
            <artifactId>automaton</artifactId>
            <version>1.11-8</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.pig</groupId>
            <artifactId>piggybank</artifactId>
            <version>0.12.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.11</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.0.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                            <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
                            <mainClass>PIGScript.PIGScript_Sample.PIGScript</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                            <mainClass>PIGScript.PIGScript_Sample.PIGScript</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Is that normal or Something i have missed out? Please let me know.

**Update:**

I have noticed when i execute the job in Eclipse new MapReduce entry available in History UI (IPAddress:8088), but when i execute the same type of job in JAR file no new entry present in History UI. I have seen in Google If PIG script running in Local mode does not produce statistics, Is that from JAR file PIG script running as local mode? How can i decide whether the Job is running as Local Mode or MapReduce Mode?

Comment: Updated new finding/question in Update Section

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have changed the below section in POM file

```
 <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                            <mainClass>PIGScript.PIGScript_Sample.PIGScript</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

With new modified plugin

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy</id>
                        <phase>install</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/lib</outputDirectory>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

used **clean install** maven command, everything worked now it show correct statistics, Hope some of the dependency jar files not updated previously. So that only it runs in local mode. I am not expert in Hadoop it just because of assumption.